# Webpack / Babel Error: Module build failed: (SystemJS) ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm looking for help with the following error when running webpack if anyone can kindly offer some advice. It seems to me that the path being used is develop/babel-core rather than develop/node_modules/babe-core but I may be off the mark here. Webpack and Babel are using the latest versions.

```
ERROR in ./js/scripts.js Module build failed: (SystemJS) ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'/Users/dh/Documents/Websites/www.mpp.dev/wp-content/themes/develop/babel-core'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'/Users/dh/Documents/Websites/www.mpp.dev/wp-content/themes/develop/babel-core'

Error loading
/Users/dh/Documents/Websites/www.mpp.dev/wp-content/themes/develop/babel-core
as "babel-core" from
/Users/dh/Documents/Websites/www.mpp.dev/wp-content/themes/develop/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js

ERROR in ./js/admin.js Module build failed: (SystemJS) ENOENT: no such
file or directory, open
'/Users/dh/Documents/Websites/www.mpp.dev/wp-content/themes/develop/babel-core'
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'/Users/dh/Documents/Websites/www.mpp.dev/wp-content/themes/develop/babel-core'

Error loading
/Users/dh/Documents/Websites/www.mpp.dev/wp-content/themes/develop/babel-core
as "babel-core" from
/Users/dh/Documents/Websites/www.mpp.dev/wp-content/themes/develop/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
```

This is my config and I think the syntax is correct.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        scripts: './js/scripts.js',
        admin: './js/admin.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'build/js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'build/js/[id].js'
    },
        module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {                                                                                                          loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
            presets: ['env']
        },                                                                      },
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

I meet the similar question with `/node_modules/babe-core` not found, and I solved by:

```
npm install postcss-import@8.0.2 --save-dev
```

see: [babel-loader#242](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/242)